# Adding Key From Input Hashtable To Output Hashtable

Tags: powershell, key, hashtable

I would like to use the keys from an input hashtable (`$htInput`) in an output hashtable (`$htOutput`) without knowing the specific key names only their numeric position. Can I access the individual input hashtable keys using the `$counter` variable in the `for` loop:

```
$main = {
    Begin {
        Write-Host "SO Question Begin..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
    }
    Process {
        try {
            $htInput = @{Alpha = 1; Bravo = 2; Charlie = 3; Delta = 4; Echo = 5}
            $htOutput = @()
            for ($counter = 0; $counter -lt $htInput.Count; $counter++) {
                $rzlt = $rzlt + $counter
                $htOutput += $rzlt
            }
            # Expected Output: $htOutput = @{Alpha = 0; Bravo = 1; Charlie = 3; Delta = 6; Echo = 10}
            # Actual Output  : $htOutput = @(0; 1; 3; 6; 10)
            return $htOutput
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception)" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red 
            break
        }
    }
    End {
        if ($?) {
            Write-Host "SO Question End..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
        }
    }
}

& $main
```

The expected output is:

```
$htOutput = @{Alpha = 0; Bravo = 1; Charlie = 3; Delta = 6; Echo = 10}
```

but the actual output is:

```
$htOutput = @(0; 1; 3; 6; 10)
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels like a homework.  However, I see your sincere effort which I like.  You get your result in Array - `$htOutput = @()` as you have defined the result to be array.  You need to have it as Hash table - `$htOutput = @{}`.

Note: It is good to have all variables initialized.  Second thing to note is that he sorting via `.GetEnumerator` can be influenced by your regional settings.  Which can cause deviation from your wished result.

```
$main = {
    begin {
        Write-Host "SO Question Begin..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
    }
    process {
        try {
            $htInput = @{Alpha = 1; Bravo = 2; Charlie = 3; Delta = 4; Echo = 5}
            $htOutput = @{}
            $temp = 0
            $counter = 0
            ForEach ($item in $htInput.GetEnumerator()) {
                $temp = $temp + $counter
                $htOutput.Add($item.key,$temp)
                $counter++
            }
            # Expected Output: $htOutput = @{Alpha = 0; Bravo = 1; Charlie = 3; Delta = 6; Echo = 10}
            # Actual Output  : $htOutput = @(0; 1; 3; 6; 10)
            return $htOutput
        } 
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception)" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red 
            break
        }
    }
    end {
        If ($?) {
            Write-Host "SO Question End..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
        }
    }
}

& $main
```